# Magnific popup zoom effect doesn`t work with AngularJS <ng-view>

Tags: angularjs, magnific-popup

i have problem with magnific popup zoom effect, i put everythink i need, i try everythink! I use AngularJS, ng-repeat also, i print images in my template like this

```
<div class="images" ng-repeat="cert in db.images">
    <a class="image-zoom" href="{{cert.image}}">
        <img ng-src="{{cert.image}}">
    </a>
</div>
```

then i put magnific `script` also, but it doesn`t work. When i use magnific zoomer outside the `<ng-view>`, in index file, it work, but when i load template and try to use magnific zoomer there, it doesn`t work. Can you tell me what i need to do for fixing this little problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How are you invoking the magnific popup? You need to create a directive that invokes the magnific popup on the elements so you are sure the popup is created even if Angular injects the elements dynamically.

```
.directive('magnificImage', magnificImageDirective);

function maginificImageDirective() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function (scope, iElement) {
            scope.$evalAsync(function () {
                iElement.magnificPopup({
                    // ... magnific options
                });
            });
        }
    };
}
```

And, apply this directive on your images:

```
<div class="images" ng-repeat="cert in db.images">
    <a class="image-zoom" magnific-image href="{{ cert.image }}">
        <img ng-src="{{ cert.image }}">
    </a>
</div>
```

Comment: The magnific zoom works now but doesn`t show the images server/undefined 404 (Not Found)

Comment: Check the edit. Also note, the directive is applied on anchor element.